# Test a Sinatra app with RSpec - "structure" of tests

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app with the following structure:

```
controllers
helpers
models
views
public
```

I will be using RSpec for testing it. For me, there are two variants of tests - to test with Rack::Test::Methods - to check responses, the content of body and so on, and the second - to test the "core" logic - for example if the method "find_most_expensive" really returns the item with maximum price, to check if a new product is really created and that kind of things.

What I'm wondering is how to organise this tests in the spec folder? Should I have only name_of_controller_spec.rb files and both kind of tests go there? Or should they be separate? And how? To sum up, I have never written tests and I don'y know how exactly and where to put them :( Any kind of advise would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make just three folders: `controllers` (with, for example, `posts_spec.rb`), `models` (that contains `post_spec.rb` where testing the methods you have implemented in your model) and `helpers` (let's say `utils_spec.rb`).

Take a look at [Testing Sinatra with Rack::Test](http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html) and some repositories on GitHub to have a better idea on how you should organize your code.

Answer (score 0):

https://pragprog.com/book/7web/seven-web-frameworks-in-seven-weeks

The source code is free and it has a chapter on Sinatra tests.
I know, I just ran them as I updated the expect instead of should deprecation warnings.
Only they use shell scripts to test with but you may already be familiar with what you want to use. The point is notice just different names for the folders and not the tests? Maybe could work for you. I like the answer first posted. These can both relate perhaps.

Something I had noticed with Rubocop is to keep your test methods in as little as 25 lines or they fail there. So I would say keep them broken down into small groups.

Ruby koans has tests that you could look at too.